# What happens in a Geiger-Müller tube when there is no voltage?

Tags: geiger-muller-tube

What happens in a Geiger-Müller tube when it is not connected to a circuit?

Ionizing radiation must still be creating ions inside it, but they cannot move to the anode because there is no potential difference. What happens to them?

Comment: Presumably they just recombine with their own electrons, probably in a fraction of the quench time.

Comment: They recombine?

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Ok thanks.